# Android Random Number Generator Hangs

Tags: android

I'm writing a very simple program. What I want is a 50/50 chance and display option A or option B.

Here is my code:

```
int min = 0;
int max = 100;
int randomValue;
randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);
btn_50_50.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (randomValue < 50) {

                // do something

                randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1);

            } else if (randomValue > 50) {

                // do something else

                randomValue = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(min, max + 1); 
            }
        }
    });
```

It works but if i press the button many times, especially if I kind of spam it, it stops working and only displays the last generated option.

I checked with a Toast message and it seems that it stops generating new numbers. It happens both in emulator and on a real device.

I have also tried importing `java.util.Random`  and using that but exactly the same results.

Is there any better way to do this or a way to force the RNG to restart?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when randomValue is exactly 50? :)
It's a 1 in 100 chance but it's bound to happen at some point.

---

Also, a 50/50 chance is the same as having 2 options and the chance of it being one of the options.
For example rolling (0,1) and checking if it's 0:

```
boolean isRandomChance = random.nextInt(0, 2) == 0;
```

Or, just the built in random boolean generator (true/false):

```
boolean isRandomChance = random.nextBoolean();
```

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. And I feel kind of stupid :(